# Duplicate symbols when integrating a static library

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, static-libraries, duplicate-symbol

I'm having a problem when integrating a static library into my project. The problem happens because I have a prior framework inside my project and when I add the static library it makes a duplicate problem.
Here is the problem:

```
duplicate symbol _HandlerException
duplicate symbol _InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler
duplicate symbol _SignalHandler
duplicate symbol _UncaughtExceptionCount
```

[image]

I really appreciate your help by giving me some ideas, Thanks in advance.